# Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04 freezes entire computer when launched after update to 97

Tags: 18.04, updates, google-chrome

I updated Chrome through the regular Ubuntu software updater after being prompted to do so. This updated me to version 97 (specifically: 97.0.4692.71-1). The update didn't give any issues, but the next time I started Chrome it froze my entire computer, to the point that I had to do a hard reset.

So I uninstalled (with `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`) and reinstalled Chrome (downloading the .deb from the website, both double-clicking it and running it through the command line), and the issue remains. After launching it I don't even see a new tab (just the Google Chrome logo in the very top bar) and the cursor freezes up completely. I can't do anything else either.

I have removed and re-downloaded the .deb and repeated the process to ensure that it wasn't a corrupted file or anything, but same issue. I also updated my NVIDIA drivers (from 470 to 495, using "Software & Updates").

Update: I downloaded the beta (version 98.0.4758.54) and that works just fine. I'd still like to get the stable version working though.